# (Flutter) How do I prevent Android device Display size scaling in my app?

Tags: android, flutter

(Flutter) How do I prevent Android device Display size scaling in my app?

I use MediaQuery to lock the font size.

```
builder: (context, child) {
  return MediaQuery(
    child: child!,
    data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
  );
},
```

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjPjr.jpg)

However, there is a setting called "Display Size" in the Android phone.

This setting scales my flutter App and make the content out of bound.

How do I prevent it?

Comment: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0), didn't fix your porblem?

Comment: It can lock the font size in my app but cannot prevent "Display size" scaling my app

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue in Flutter, regarding modifying the logical pixel size, which is related to the problem you're having: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32115

- Do note, There is a property in the MediaQuery called devicePixelRatio which updates when "Display size" changes in the settings.
- **Unfortunately**, devicePixelRatio does not affect the sizing of the widgets, the size of widgets would change - even if you provide a custom fixed value.

I would suggest you to:

- Either see if any workarounds or packages suggested in the issue above is suitable for your problem.
- Or maybe preferably, update the content of your app to be more responsive to different accessibility settings like text size or display size.

Answer (score 0):

devicepixel ration just can detact the size of the screne but not the applied height of the widgets so for this question textScaleFactor and devicepixel both property of the Mediaqueary.copywith (Factory Constructor)'s property can not work give some external dependency or accurate solution

Answer (score -2):

The MediaQuery can lock the option for size inside your application but not for the Mobile Phone Display Scaling option. For further responsiveness you can use multiple other options like

- Layout Builder
- Fitted Box (To wrap Text widget)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).